# how to stop image squeezes when keyboad comes up android

Tags: android, android-layout

I test my application on 800x420 and galaxy sl and s2 mobile.
in galaxy sl when I press Edit text keyboard comes up but background image is not squeezed but in galaxy s2 it is squeezed. both are same dispaly size and galaxy sl uses gingerbread.

here is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/page1background"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_large" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_Title_Top"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/backbut"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
            android:onClick="onClickBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/backarrowpress" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/copyButton"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/copy"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
            android:onClick="onClickBtn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

if anybody can help me to correct this.
thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi try to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to your activity tag in the manifest.xml.

like below

```
        <activity
            android:name=".youractivitywhichyouhaveproblem" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: then I cant select what I want from the text to copy.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" is useful for my requirment. thx

Comment: Plase dont forget to upvote and mark as answer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following.

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"

put this entry in manifest file.